# Returning only once all websocket messages are processed in Python asyncio

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I am working with a streaming API from Kucoin (crypto exchange) which sends `order_book` updates, and I am trying to process inbound `order_book` websocket messages using a message handler method and then only return once all messages are processed, but I think I am designing the pattern wrong or otherwise misunderstanding async & websockets.

What I want is something like this - below code doesn't work, but for illustrative purposes it's what I'm trying to achieve, so please bear with my lizard brain on this.

```
async for message in websocket:
    message_handled = handler_method(message)  # this updates self.order_book
    if websocket.index(message) + 1 == len(websocket): # check if this is final message
        return self.order_book
```

What is the correct way to do this so all the `message`s are processed by `handler_method()` before returning?

EDIT:

Please see example debug logs for the websocket.

````
client - event = data_received(<1016 bytes>)
client < Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"data":{"sequence":1627402741271,"change":"2346.05,buy,120","timestamp":1627660760709},"subject":"level2","topic":"/contractMarket/level2:ETHUSDTM","type":"message"}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
client < Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"data":{"sequence":1627402741272,"change":"2345.1,buy,33","timestamp":1627660760710},"subject":"level2","topic":"/contractMarket/level2:ETHUSDTM","type":"message"}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
client < Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"data":{"sequence":1627402741273,"change":"2346.1,buy,3360","timestamp":1627660760710},"subject":"level2","topic":"/contractMarket/level2:ETHUSDTM","type":"message"}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
client < Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"data":{"sequence":1627402741274,"change":"2346.15,sell,0","timestamp":1627660760710},"subject":"level2","topic":"/contractMarket/level2:ETHUSDTM","type":"message"}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
client < Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"data":{"sequence":1627402741275,"change":"2346.85,sell,0","timestamp":1627660760710},"subject":"level2","topic":"/contractMarket/level2:ETHUSDTM","type":"message"}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
client < Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"data":{"sequence":1627402741276,"change":"2346.05,buy,540","timestamp":1627660760710},"subject":"level2","topic":"/contractMarket/level2:ETHUSDTM","type":"message"}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
client - event = data_received(<849 bytes>)
client < Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"data":{"sequence":1627402741277,"change":"2344.8,buy,2145","timestamp":1627660760724},"subject":"level2","topic":"/contractMarket/level2:ETHUSDTM","type":"message"}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
client < Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"data":{"sequence":1627402741278,"change":"2344.8,buy,1667","timestamp":1627660760724},"subject":"level2","topic":"/contractMarket/level2:ETHUSDTM","type":"message"}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
client < Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"data":{"sequence":1627402741279,"change":"2346.1,buy,3780","timestamp":1627660760724},"subject":"level2","topic":"/contractMarket/level2:ETHUSDTM","type":"message"}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
client < Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"data":{"sequence":1627402741280,"change":"2344.8,buy,1189","timestamp":1627660760724},"subject":"level2","topic":"/contractMarket/level2:ETHUSDTM","type":"message"}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
client < Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"data":{"sequence":1627402741281,"change":"2344.8,buy,711","timestamp":1627660760724},"subject":"level2","topic":"/contractMarket/level2:ETHUSDTM","type":"message"}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
client - event = data_received(<1690 bytes>)
client < Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"data":{"sequence":1627402741282,"change":"2346.05,buy,120","timestamp":1627660760755},"subject":"level2","topic":"/contractMarket/level2:ETHUSDTM","type":"message"}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
client < Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"data":{"sequence":1627402741283,"change":"2338.1,buy,407","timestamp":1627660760755},"subject":"level2","topic":"/contractMarket/level2:ETHUSDTM","type":"message"}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
client < Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"data":{"sequence":1627402741284,"change":"2360.25,sell,9681","timestamp":1627660760755},"subject":"level2","topic":"/contractMarket/level2:ETHUSDTM","type":"message"}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
client < Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"data":{"sequence":1627402741285,"change":"2337.8,buy,20","timestamp":1627660760755},"subject":"level2","topic":"/contractMarket/level2:ETHUSDTM","type":"message"}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
client < Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"data":{"sequence":1627402741286,"change":"2338.1,buy,6","timestamp":1627660760755},"subject":"level2","topic":"/contractMarket/level2:ETHUSDTM","type":"message"}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
client < Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"data":{"sequence":1627402741287,"change":"2334.1,buy,0","timestamp":1627660760755},"subject":"level2","topic":"/contractMarket/level2:ETHUSDTM","type":"message"}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
client < Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"data":{"sequence":1627402741288,"change":"2346.1,buy,3360","timestamp":1627660760755},"subject":"level2","topic":"/contractMarket/level2:ETHUSDTM","type":"message"}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
client < Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"data":{"sequence":1627402741289,"change":"2346.2,buy,120","timestamp":1627660760755},"subject":"level2","topic":"/contractMarket/level2:ETHUSDTM","type":"message"}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
client < Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"data":{"sequence":1627402741290,"change":"2346.1,buy,3780","timestamp":1627660760755},"subject":"level2","topic":"/contractMarket/level2:ETHUSDTM","type":"message"}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
client < Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"data":{"sequence":1627402741291,"change":"2354.3,sell,0","timestamp":1627660760755},"subject":"level2","topic":"/contractMarket/level2:ETHUSDTM","type":"message"}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)```
````

Comment: Streams don't have "length" or "end". What do you mean by "once all messages are processed"? What exactly is the last message in a stream? If there actually is some marker, then this becomes rather simple: load all messages up to the marker, process them, return. Websockets themeselves have such marker, `FIN` message. But that's assuming you actually use it.

Comment: Ah - sorry. Every time data is received it is coming in as a bunch of separate Frames (not sure if that's the right word), and I want to 1) process all of those frames using `handler_method`, then 2) `return` something, then 3) give control back to the event loop. See updated question with logs, which might better illustrate how the data is arriving.

Comment: So you do know how those separate frames form a complete data set? You know how to detect that (cause it isn't obvious for me from what you've shown us)? So what seems to be an issue? What do you mean by "return"? With that setup you wait for all messages from the given data set and send a response once you process them all. Is that what you want? I have problems understanding yours "return self.order_book" line. There is no "return" with websockets, only receive and send, it's a stream. Are you using some framework that requires a "return"? If so, maybe you should switch to something else.

Comment: Thanks for your patience - so in the above example, I want my `async for` loop to return 3 times during the process of handling all 21 of the example frames, once after each batch is handled. I.e., handle the first 6 frames, then return, then handle the next batch of 5 frames, then return, then handle the next 10 frames, then return. If I just put a return statement in the `async for` loop, it returns after each frame is received and handled instead of batching them together, handling each frame from the batch, and then returning only once all frames from the batch are handled.

Comment: And by `return`, I mean it in the normal sense of a Python function, returning a result at the completion of a function.

Comment: It will be hard to implement this with the standard function return. Nor there is a need for that. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will be helpful to anyone else in the future but I ended up solving this by calling `websocket.recv()` and then using a while loop to process the `ws.messages` queue of messages directly. See below example:

```
message = json.loads(await ws.recv())
handler_method(message)

while len(ws.messages) > 0:
    message = json.loads(ws.messages.popleft())
    handler_method(message)

return something
```

What this does is: `recv` receives all the messages from the websocket connection, loads them up in the `ws.messages` queue (a `collections.deque` object), and calls `ws.messages.popleft()` once which yields an individual message to handle. Then we simply call `ws.messages.popleft()` inside a while loop until there are no remaining messages, and finally `return` after the conclusion of the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are designing this thing, so let me give you some hints. First of all, it is typical in the networking to send one message in separate chunks. But in order for that to work correctly you need to do some additional stuff. The most importantly: you need boundaries, a way to communicate to your server the begining and end of this chunked message.

For example you may assume that messages come in strict order: for a given data set X with chunks A_1,...,A_k you design your protocol to first send "new data set with k chunks" message and then each chunk A_i sequentially. That would be similar to HTTP and its "Content-Length:" header which is followed with content of concrete length. A variant of that is that you send "new data set" message, then all A_i sequentially and "end of data set" message. This is how HTTP with "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" header works.

An alternative is to send "new data set of Id T with k chunks" message and then add the id "T" to each chunk. This allows you to process things asynchronously (for example interleave two data sets at the same time). So it is obviously beneficial, but harder to implement correctly.

Once you design your protocol you have to implement your server side. Depending on the approach it will have a different implementation. For example for the sequential scenario this is quite easy. Here's a pseudocode:

```py
while True:
    message = await websocket.receive()  # <-- assumed to be the initial "new data set" message

    # TODO: break if disconnected or invalid message

    total_chunks_length = get_chunks_length(message)
    total_processed_data = []
    while total_chunks_length > 0:
        message = await websocket.receive()
        processed_data = await handler_method(message)
        total_processed_data.append(processed_data)
        total_chunks_length -= 1

    await websocket.send(total_processed_data)
```

This becomes more difficult with the second, asynchronous design, because you have to keep track of ids. I won't go into details here, hopefuly you can come up with a solution.

Comment: This was helpful - thanks again for all your help! See my Answer for how I ended up solving it.